# Is this onClick JavaScript event is not accepting in POST section?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am writing a blog post on my WordPress website and I need show following HTML code:

```
<button type=”button” onclick=”getData()”>Get Data</button>
```

Now, if I press the preview button then it’s showing me Post Not Found Error message. Very strange? If I change the onClick to something else then it’s working. So I think the issues on the onClick event.

If you can then try to post above HTML code in your WordPres Blog Post editor and then press preview button :(

Can you tell me how can I solve it?

Thank You.

**Updated:**

Maybe I can't explain my question properly :(

I have a WordPress blog website where I am writing a tutorial about HMTL and CSS. You know if you write a tutorial blog you need to show some textual code to the user, right?

Yes, I am doing the same thing. I need to write above HMTL code as textual version but when I press the preview button it's showing me Not Found Error Message.

**Note:** It's not an actual JS function.

I have another code that's showing perfectly on the blog page. Check this image.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please add code of fruntion getData

Comment: What does the function getData()? Edit ur post so we can help you out

Comment: I don't think that I need to write more code because I just want to write a Blog Post using WordPress where I need to write an HTML code. So when I write that HTML it's showing me Not Found Error Message on the front-end. That's I am requesting you to try the above code in your WordPress Blog Post then you can understand. I have tried another WP site too :(

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by this way please check below code example I have given.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#getData").click(function(){
    //Do some action
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type=”button” id="getData">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: Maybe, I am wrong and I can not explain my question properly :( I am writing a blog post about HTML and JavaScript in my WordPress Tutorial Blog where I need to write the above HTML code in the POST Editor Box. Not an actual function.

Comment: So in this case you can add your html and JS code in blog's "Text" section not "Visual" section.
I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: &lt;button type="button" onclick="getData()"&gt;Get Data&lt;/button&gt;

Comment: Add this code in your wordpress page this will show button code instead of actual button.

Comment: I write that code in visual section but still same error :(

Comment: Not the visual section you have to write that into "Text" section of wordpress editor

Comment: Unfortunately, Same error. If you have a WordPress website then can you try it by yourself ?

Comment: https://www.isitwp.com/how-to-display-code-in-wordpress-posts-and-pages/

Comment: I am using this plugin: Crayon Syntax Highlighter to post the code but no luck :(

Comment: I think above solutions should work. Provide credentials if you can so I can check.

Comment: let me disabled few plugins first.